# What existing relationships are there in the divisor counting function for τ(m), τ(n) and τ(mn)?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisor-counting-function

I'm currently working through Fundamentals of Number Theory by LeVeque, and one of the problems asks whether I can find some relationship between $τ(m)$, $τ(n)$ and $τ(mn)$, where $τ$ is the number of positive integers that divide its input.

The best I've been able to find is

$$τ(m)τ(n) = τ(mn) + R$$

where

$$R = τ\bigl(ε(m, n)\bigl)τ\bigl(ε(n, m)\bigl) \biggl[ τ\bigl(\frac{m}{ε(m, n)}\bigl) τ\bigl(\frac{n}{ε(n, m)}\bigl) 
 - τ\bigl(\frac{mn}{ε(m, n)ε(n, m)}\bigl) \biggl]$$

where I've defined $ε(x, y)$ as a function which outputs $x$ after it is divided to the point of no longer sharing prime factors with $y$ (so, if $x=y$ then $ε(x, y)=1$, and if $gcd(x, y)=1$ then $ε(x, y)=x$, etc.).

I'm fairly sure about the logic behind this result and have tested it successfully. However, it isn't particularly useful or elegant.

I have two questions:

1. What established relationships between $τ(m)$, $τ(n)$ and $τ(mn)$ are there in the literature?
2. Does there exist a function which does what I've defined $ε(x, y)$ to do?

Comment: 1. The only relationship I know is for coprime $m,n$, which I'm sure this question is not about. 2. We have $\epsilon(x,y) = \dfrac x {\gcd (x,y)}$.

Comment: As stated this is quite vague. One relationship is that $\tau(m)\tau(n) \ge \tau(mn)$ for all $m$ and $n$. Another relationship, which holds for any multiplicative function, is $\tau(m)\tau(n) = \tau(\gcd(m,n)) \tau(\mathop{\rm lcm}(m,n))$.

Comment: @player3236, regarding 2: that's not quite right. If you consider $x=400=2^4 \times 5^2$ and $y=230=2^1 \times 5^1 \times 23^1$, the greatest common divisor is $10=2^1 \times 5^1$, but if you divide $x$ by it, it will still share prime factors with $y$: $400 \div 10 = 40 = 2^3 \times 5^1$. The output for $ε(400, 230)$ is $1$. I'm not sure how to more precisely express this idea. If the prime factorisations of $x$ and $y$ both have twos and fives, $x$ must be divided until it has neither.

Comment: Ah I see. In that case it will be "the greatest divisor of $x$ that is coprime to $y$"

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2179976/identity-for-the-divisor-function-taumn-sum-limits-d-midm-n-mud-tau), as well as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3339946/where-does-the-identity-taunm-sum-d-mid-m-n-mud-taun-d-taum) may be of interest.